# Search words in an object with array values

Tags: javascript, performance, search

I have this object:

```
let units = {
    "MPa" : ["mpa","megapascal", "mega pascal"],
    "N*m" : ["n*m","newton meter"],
    "Ohm" : ["ohm","ohms"],
    ...
}
```

I am supposed to search this object with another string with words (units in this case). I have come up with a solution but it won't be efficient if the size of the object increases. My solution is

```
for (let key in units) {
    for (let val in units[key]) {
         if (string.includes(units[key][val])) {
             // some code
         }
    }
}
```

I want know if there are other efficient ways to do this.

Comment: What is `list` in your code ? I suppose would be `units[key][val]` also.

Comment: is there only one value on the object to find?

Comment: @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut I have edited the question, it was supposed to be string

Comment: @NinaScholz One string can have multiple units

Comment: @user3316224 What is intents here?

Comment: @NabinPaudyal Sorry, I was supposed to be units.

Comment: Did you read the usage description of the `json` tag? Hint: it does not belong here.

Comment: @trincot I don't know what you are talking about. And I didn't read any usage description.

Comment: @user3316224 What should be done if (string.includes(units[key][val])) returns true?

Comment: @NabinPaudyal I want the key and unit found to be stored. Note: there can be multiple such units found with different key.

Comment: @user3316224, my point is that JavaScript questions that concern object literals should not be tagged with `json`. JSON is a text format. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json

Answer (score 1):

It's really hard to answer your question without more detail, specially what happens inside the `if` statement.

There could be a nice way to do it using `find` and other filters. but more information is needed.

Here is your code, slightly cleaner:

```
Object.keys(units)
    .map(k => units[k])
    .reduce((xs,ys) => xs.concat(ys), [])
    .forEach(item => {
        if (string.includes(item)) {...}
    });
```

`item` above would be in order `"mpa","megapascal", "mega pascal", "n*m","newton meter", "ohm","ohms"`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to replace the alternative names for a unit with their "standard" names, you could use this function:

```js
function harmoniseUnits(str, units) {
    // store the relation in opposite direction: 
    // - key is the substring to be found, value is the standard unit
    units = Object.entries(units).reduce( (acc, [unit, alts]) =>
        Object.assign(acc, ...alts.map( alt => ({ [alt]: unit }) )),
        {}
    );
    // turn this into a regular expression
    const regex = new RegExp(
        Object.keys(units)
            // sort the terms putting the longest first
            .sort( (a, b) => b.length - a.length )
            // escape characters for use in regex
            .map( alt => alt.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&') )
            // make them part of an OR-expression
            .join('|'),
    "gi");
    // use a callback to replace the words with the standard unit code
    return str.replace(regex, m => units[m])
}
// Example use:
const units = {
        "MPa" : ["mpa","megapascal", "mega pascal"],
        "N*m" : ["n*m","newton meter"],
        "Ohm" : ["ohm","ohms"],
    },
    str = "We have 12 megapascal, while the resistance is just 0.4 ohms",
    result = harmoniseUnits(str, units);

console.log(result);
```

It preprocesses the `units` object into an "inverted" object and a corresponding regular expression.

If you plan to use the same `units` object for processing many different strings, then it would be good to generate this inverted object and the regular expression only once. With those two elements ready, you can just do the replacement with:

```
    str.replace(regex, m => units[m])
```